# unable to use color.xml file in eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i'm getting a no resources found at that given name @color/red. i have no clue why the colors are being recognized on my displayStudentInfo.activity. Please help.

Here is my colors.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
  <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
  <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
  <color name="black">#000000</color>

</resources>
```

Here is my DisplayStudentInfo.activity file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<TextView    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/line1"
    android:textColor="@color/red" />

<TextView    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/line2" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/line3"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/line4"/>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the above xml file a class?

Comment: I didn't mean to just changed it

Comment: `DisplayStudentInfo.activity` is this the **exact** name of the file?

Comment: no its activity_display_student_info.xml

Comment: @user3242607 does blue work?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to android but i think your problem is your colors.xml file.
Your file should look something like this (https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicMediaRouter/res/values/colors.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
    <item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
    <item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
    <item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
    <item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>

    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/darkblue</item>
        <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
        <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
        <item>@color/darkorange</item>
        <item>@color/darkred</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```